# Data binding of fragment view pager while using dagger in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2

Basically I have an application, my MainActivity have a home fragment which have a tab layout and a viewpager with data binding. This view pager will contain two child fragments.

I have this exception:

```
01-28 18:46:44.692 24073-24073/app.series.com.tvshowsapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.series.com.tvshowsapplication, PID: 24073
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.series.com.tvshowsapplication/app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.ui.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment.getChildFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment.getChildFragmentManager()' on a null object reference
   at app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.ui.home.HomeFragmentViewModel.bindViewPagerAdapter(HomeFragmentViewModel.java:24)
   at app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.databinding.HomeFragmentBinding.executeBindings(HomeFragmentBinding.java:123)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:379)
   at android.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:351)
   at app.series.com.tvshowsapplication.ui.base.BaseFragment.onViewCreated(BaseFragment.java:63)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1430)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1412)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7015)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
01-28 18:46:44.694 24073-24073/app.series.com.tvshowsapplication D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

This is my HomeFragmentViewModel

```
@Module
public class HomeFragmentViewModel extends BaseViewModel<HomeNavigator>{

    public HomeFragmentViewModel()
    {
        super();
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:handler"})
    public static void bindViewPagerAdapter(final ViewPager view, final HomeFragment homeFragment) {
        final HomeFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentPagerAdapter(view.getContext(), homeFragment.getChildFragmentManager());
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"bind:pager"})
    public static void bindViewPagerTabs(final TabLayout view, final ViewPager pagerView) {
        view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true);
    }

}
```

The exception happened when the application is trying to create the new adapter of the viewpager. 
One of the arguments of bindViewPagerAdapter function is HomeFragment but the binding occur in onCreateView so technically there is no HomeFragment yet, which leads to null pointer exception. I would still need to pass a childfragmentmanager from somewhere. Is there any option to invoke the binding in onViewCreated instead of onCreateView or am I missing something.

This is the code of HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment<HomeFragmentBinding, HomeFragmentViewModel> {

        public static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

        @Inject
        HomeFragmentViewModel mHomeFragmentViewModel;


        public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public HomeFragmentViewModel getViewModel() {
            return mHomeFragmentViewModel;
        }

        @Override
        public int getBindingVariable() {
            return BR.viewModel;
        }

        @Override
        public int getLayoutId() {
            return R.layout.home_fragment;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
        }
    }
```